Listen to multiple riverpod stream providers in a widget
I have this code:
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
   final bookingAsync = ref.watch(streamBookingProvider(rideId, userId!));
   bool showBookingFab = false;
   showBookingFab = bookingAsync.maybeWhen(
     data: (booking) => booking == null,
     orElse: () => false,
   );


   final rideAsync = ref.watch(streamRideProvider(rideId));
   return rideAsync.when(
     data: (ride) => RideScreenCompact(
       ride: ride,
       userId: userId,
       showBookingFab: showBookingFab,
     ),
     error: (e, st) => PullRidesErrorWidget(
       message: tr(context).errorPullRide,
     ),
     loading: () => const Center(child: CircularPBar()),
   );

Basically I would like to know if there is a downside to listening to multiple stream providers within a build.
I assume that some streams may return quicker than others. I have some widgets where I am listening to up to 4 streams because I need their result to build the screens or the display or not display some widgets.
Is there a better way to do so?
I have seen implementation such as:
if (bookingAsync.isLoading || rideAsync.isLoading) {
  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
if (bookingAsync.hasError || rideAsync.hasError) {
  return PullRidesErrorWidget(
    message: tr(context).errorPullRide,
  );
}

but at the same time the documentation says bool get isLoading:

/// Whether some new value is currently asynchronously loading.
///
/// Even if [isLoading] is true, it is still possible for [hasValue]/[hasError]
/// to also be true.

I have been also experimenting with the following:
bool isLoading = false;
bool hasError = false;
Ride? ride;
Profile? profile;
Booking? booking;

rideAsync.when(data: (data) {
  ride = data;
}, error: (err, st) {
  hasError = true;
}, loading: () {
  isLoading = true;
});

bookingAsync.when(data: (data) {
  booking = data;
}, error: (err, st) {
  hasError = true;
}, loading: () {
  isLoading = true;
});

